# Is "Using{}" good practice to dispose object even if there is no variable referring to it

Tags: c#, idisposable, using

In my company, I am seeing code like this

```
using (LoggerFactory.GetTracer(_log.ModuleName + "._GetAccessTokenFromWns"))
{...}
```

When I looked up, I learned it disposes the objects referred by variables declared inside "Using" parenthesis.

Does it also help for code like above, where there is no variable referring to the object returned by the factory?

Thanks,

Comment: No variable is required, the compiler allocates an unnamed one to store the reference.  Which is does whether you use a named variable or not, it doesn't trust you enough and expects you to do something unwise like assigning another reference to that variable inside the using block.  It makes no difference whatsoever at runtime.  Look at the MSIL with ildasm.exe to see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I see your question I write a simple code like this:

```
using (new FileStream("sample.txt",FileMode.CreateNew))
{

}
```

And then I look at the produced `IL code`:

```
    .method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       35 (0x23)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.FileStream CS$3$0000,
           [1] bool CS$4$0001)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "asdas.txt"
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0007:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.FileStream::.ctor(string,
                                                                           valuetype [mscorlib]System.IO.FileMode)
  IL_000c:  stloc.0
  .try
  {
    IL_000d:  nop
    IL_000e:  nop
    IL_000f:  leave.s    IL_0021
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0011:  ldloc.0
    IL_0012:  ldnull
    IL_0013:  ceq
    IL_0015:  stloc.1
    IL_0016:  ldloc.1
    IL_0017:  brtrue.s   IL_0020
    IL_0019:  ldloc.0
    IL_001a:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_001f:  nop
    IL_0020:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_0021:  nop
  IL_0022:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you can see it is still calling the `Dispose` method.It creates `FileStream` instance before `try` block, then calling the `Dispose` method in the `finally`.I think this is another advantage of `using` statements.

Comment: +1 Saying this or that is well and good but there is no substitute for actually showing that dispose is called on the unassigned object.

Answer (score 3):

"Disposal" of an object involves cleaning up any resources it may have initialized for its own use. The important task isn't cleaning up a reference, it is clearing file locks, mutexes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is the only way of ensuring the disposal of an object without introducing a variable for it. This is the same as

```
var __invisible = LoggerFactory.GetTracer(_log.ModuleName + "._GetAccessTokenFromWns");
try {
} finally {
    __invisible.Dispose();
}
```

but without the `__invisible` variable.

This construct is especially valuable in situations when you do *not* need a variable, because readers who are familiar with this idiom will find such code more readable.

Comment: Good point. Not only is the using statement *a* way to dispose of an object without having a reference to it, it is the *only* way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it still has the same effect. If `GetTracer` is returning an instance of a class which implements `IDisposable` then this code is ensuring that instance is properly disposed of. Just because there is no assignment of the return value doesn't mean a resource which requires disposal wasn't allocated. The tracer for example could be opening a file and without the `using` statement that file lock/ streamreader or whatever resource my go indisposed.

Comment: I guess, for the tracing to work correctly, we need to use such a mechanism. So the log file gets accessed only by one code at any instance, and when one lock gets "disposed", the other code can lock and log its message too. Thanks...